# How to load a video from a specific location

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I understand the idea of AVPlayer and how to use it to load&play a video. My question is how to recover the player from screen lock/app going background. By recover, I mean, for example the user quits the player on the time when the video has played 30:00 minutes. So at a later time, when the user comes back to the player, the video should be reloaded from 30:00 to the end, instead of being loaded from 0:00.

I googled about how to implement this, but it seems to me that the only option I have is to first load the video at 0:00 then quickly seekToTime to 30:00. Is there a better way? Loading 0:00 first just sounds non-optimal...

BTW, the video URL I'm playing here is fetched in m3u8 format on a server on local network. And the player is an iOS app.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have to reload the video each time the app is backgrounded? iOS doesn't terminate apps anymore when they quit...

Comment: Should we clear up memory? I thought since the video can be reloaded, we only need its URL and the time it's played. But I don't have much experience with players in any platform, so I'm not sure what's the best practice...